# create tablespace problem in db2 HADR environment

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We have Db2 10.5.0.7 on centos 6.9 and  TSAMP 3.2 as our high availability solution, when we create a tablespace in primary database we encounter the following errors in the standby:

> 2019-08-31-08.47.32.164952+270 I87056E2779           LEVEL: Error (OS)
>   PID     : 4046                 TID : 47669095425792  PROC : db2sysc 0
>   INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : SAMDB
>   APPHDL  : 0-8                  APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.190725231126
>   HOSTNAME: samdb-b EDUID   : 155                  EDUNAME: db2redom
>   (SAMDB) 0 FUNCTION: DB2 Common, OSSe, ossGetDiskInfo, probe:130
>   MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000001=-1879048191=ECF_ACCESS_DENIED
>             Access denied CALLED  : OS, -, fopen                            OSERR: EACCES (13) DATA #1 : String, 12 bytes /proc/mounts DATA #2 :
>   String, 25 bytes /dbdata1/samdbTsContainer DATA #3 : unsigned integer,
>   8 bytes
>
> 2019-08-31-08.47.32.185625+270 E89836E494            LEVEL: Error PID 
>   : 4046                 TID : 47669095425792  PROC : db2sysc 0
>   INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : SAMDB
>   APPHDL  : 0-8                  APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.190725231126
>   HOSTNAME: samdb-b EDUID   : 155                  EDUNAME: db2redom
>   (SAMDB) 0 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, high avail services,
>   sqlhaGetLocalDiskInfo, probe:9433 MESSAGE :
>   ECF=0x90000001=-1879048191=ECF_ACCESS_DENIED
>             Access denied
>
> 2019-08-31-08.47.32.186258+270 E90331E484            LEVEL: Error PID 
>   : 4046                 TID : 47669095425792  PROC : db2sysc 0
>   INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : SAMDB
>   APPHDL  : 0-8                  APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.190725231126
>   HOSTNAME: samdb-b EDUID   : 155                  EDUNAME: db2redom
>   (SAMDB) 0 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, high avail services, sqlhaCreateMount,
>   probe:9746 RETCODE : ZRC=0x827300AA=-2106392406=HA_ZRC_FAILED "SQLHA
>   API call error"
>
> 2019-08-31-08.47.32.186910+270 I90816E658            LEVEL: Error PID 
>   : 4046                 TID : 47669095425792  PROC : db2sysc 0
>   INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : SAMDB
>   APPHDL  : 0-8                  APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.190725231126
>   HOSTNAME: samdb-b EDUID   : 155                  EDUNAME: db2redom
>   (SAMDB) 0 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services,
>   sqlbDMSAddContainerRequest, probe:812 MESSAGE :
>   ZRC=0x827300AA=-2106392406=HA_ZRC_FAILED "SQLHA API call error" DATA
>   : String, 36 bytes Cluster add mount operation failed: DATA #2 : String, 37 bytes /dbdata1/samdbTsContainer/TSPKGCACH.1 DATA #3 :
>   String, 8 bytes SAMDB
>
> 2019-08-31-08.47.32.190537+270 E113909E951           LEVEL: Error PID 
>   : 4046                 TID : 47669095425792  PROC : db2sysc 0
>   INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : SAMDB
>   APPHDL  : 0-8                  APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.190725231126
>   HOSTNAME: samdb-b EDUID   : 155                  EDUNAME: db2redom
>   (SAMDB) 0 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services,
>   sqlblog_reCreatePool, probe:3134 MESSAGE : ADM6106E   Table space
>   "TSPKGCACH" (ID = "49") could not be created
>             during the rollforward operation. The most likely cause is that there
>             is not enough space to create the containers associated with the
>             table space. Connect to the database after the rollforward operation
>             completes and use the SET TABLESPACE CONTAINERS command to assign
>             containers to the table space. Then, issue another ROLLFORWARD
>             DATABASE command to complete recovery of this table space.
>
> 2019-08-31-08.47.32.200949+270 E114861E592           LEVEL: Error PID 
>   : 4046                 TID : 47669095425792  PROC : db2sysc 0
>   INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : SAMDB
>   APPHDL  : 0-8                  APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.190725231126
>   HOSTNAME: samdb-b EDUID   : 155                  EDUNAME: db2redom
>   (SAMDB) 0 FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services, sqlbIncPoolState,
>   probe:4628 MESSAGE : ADM12512W  Log replay on the HADR standby has
>   stopped on table space
>             "TSPKGCACH" (ID "49") because it has been put into "ROLLFORWARD
>             PENDING" state.

There is free space available for the database and the specified path (/dbdata1/samdbTsContainer) exists on the server and we can create file manually on it . 
all settings are equivalent on the primary and standby. db2inst1 is the owner of /dbdata1/samdbTsContainer and permission is drwxr-xr-x, the result of su - db2inst1 “ulimit -Hf” is unlimited and ext3 is file system type and create tablespace statement is as follows:

```
CREATE LARGE TABLESPACE TSPKGCACH IN DATABASE PARTITION GROUP IBMDEFAULTGROUP PAGESIZE 8 K MANAGED BY DATABASE USING (FILE '/dbdata1/samdbTsContainer/TSPKGCACH.1' 5120) ON DBPARTITIONNUM (0) EXTENTSIZE 64 PREFETCHSIZE 64 BUFFERPOOL BP8KPKGCACH OVERHEAD 10.5 TRANSFERRATE 0.14 DATA TAG NONE   NO FILE SYSTEM CACHING;
```

SELinux is disabled and the sector size is 512 bytes. The mount options are as follws:

```
/dev/sdf1 /dbdata1 ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

We can not recreate the problem sometimes this problem occur and we don't know the reason of it, but the problem remains until server reboot.
When we restart the standby server problem solves but we need to drop the tablespace and recreate it, is there any idea for this problem?

Comment: What are the OS permissions on the `/dbdata1/samdbTsContainer` directory on the standby? What’s the result of `su - db2inst1 “ulimit -Hf”` on the standby? What’s the exact `create tablespace` statement?

Comment: all settings are equivalent  on the primary and standby. db2inst1 is the owner of /dbdata1/samdbTsContainer  and permission is drwxr-xr-x,   the result of su - db2inst1 “ulimit -Hf” is unlimited and ext3 is file system type and create tablespace statement is as follows:  CREATE LARGE TABLESPACE TSPKGCACH  IN DATABASE PARTITION GROUP IBMDEFAULTGROUP  PAGESIZE 8 K  MANAGED BY DATABASE  USING (FILE '/dbdata1/samdbTsContainer/TSPKGCACH.1' 5120) ON DBPARTITIONNUM (0)  EXTENTSIZE 64 PREFETCHSIZE 64  BUFFERPOOL BP8KPKGCACH  OVERHEAD 10.5  TRANSFERRATE 0.14  DATA TAG NONE NO FILE SYSTEM CACHING;

Comment: You are using DMS FILE containers, which are deprecated since v10.1 (replaced by automatic storage) . Are there other interesting db2diag entries before the first ECF_ACCESS_DENIED (at DIAGLEVEL 4) , and are there any timestamp-matching entries in the operating system message log ? Please supply the mount options for the file system.  Please add the new facts to the question (use EDIT to add new facts), instead of adding as comments. Please also add the CREATE TABLEPACE to the question by editing the question.

Comment: @Sara Did you have the same problems with other tablespaces earlier? Do you use SELinux on the standby? What’s the sector size of disk(s) where this file system resides?

Comment: There is not any message before ECF_ACCESS_DENIED in the db2 diag or syslog and we haven't this problem for already created tablespaces. I add other details to the question

Comment: Do you have the same problem, when TSAMP automation is disabled for this database (after `db2haicu -disable` on both hosts from db2inst1)?

Comment: Please also edit your question to add whether this symptom recreates on-demand on a non-production environment. If you can recreate it, you can get more diagnostics (tracing etc).

Comment: We have the same problem when tsamp automation is disabled

Comment: @Sara if you cannot recreate the symptom on-demand, and if you cannot recreate the symptom on a different environment, then it looks like a DEFECT but it is unclear which component, although it is more likely to be outside of Db2. Outside the remit of stackoverflow.  It's your decision as to whether it is worthwhile to dig deeper, or if it is wiser or more strategic to retest with both ext4 (or an alternative more modern fs) and automatic-storage - which may in turn depend on the expected longevity of your Db2 environments.

Answer (score 3):

From the error it looks to me that problem is not with the file access itself but rather `/proc/mounts`, which Db2 uses to do the mapping between containers and filesystems (to know e.g. the FS type). Hence I suggest to test whether all:

```
cat /proc/mounts
cat /proc/self/mounts
mount
```

work OK run as Db2 instance owner ID (db2inst1). If not, this implies some odd OS issue that Db2 is a victim of and we would need more OS diagnostics (e.g `strace` from the `cat /proc/mounts` command) to understand it.

Edit:

To confirm this theory I've run a quick test with Db2 11.1. Note this must be TSA-controlled environment for Db2 to follow `sqlhaCreateMount` code path (because if this will be a separate mount, Db2 will add it to the TSA resource model)

On both primary and standby:

```
mkdir /db2data
chown db2v111:db2iadm /db2data
```

then on standby:

```
chmod o-rx /proc
```

(couldn't find a "smarter" way to hit `EACCES` on mount info).

When I will run on primary:

```
db2 "create tablespace test managed by database using (file '/db2data/testts' 100 M)"
```

it completes fine on primary but standby hits exactly the error you are seeing:

```
2019-06-21-03.00.37.087693+120 I1774E2661            LEVEL: Error (OS)
PID     : 10379                TID : 46912992438016  PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2v111              NODE : 000            DB   : SAMPLE
APPHDL  : 0-4492               APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.190621005919
HOSTNAME: rhel-hadrs.kkuduk.com
EDUID   : 61                   EDUNAME: db2redom (SAMPLE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 Common, OSSe, ossGetDiskInfo, probe:130
MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000001=-1879048191=ECF_ACCESS_DENIED
          Access denied
CALLED  : OS, -, fopen                            OSERR: EACCES (13)
DATA #1 : String, 12 bytes
/proc/mounts
DATA #2 : String, 8 bytes
/db2data
DATA #3 : unsigned integer, 8 bytes
1
CALLSTCK: (Static functions may not be resolved correctly, as they are resolved to the nearest symbol)
  [0] 0x00002AAAB9CFD84B /home/db2v111/sqllib/lib64/libdb2osse.so.1 + 0x23F84B
  [1] 0x00002AAAB9CFED51 ossLogSysRC + 0x101
  [2] 0x00002AAAB9D19647 ossGetDiskInfo + 0xF07
  [3] 0x00002AAAAC52402C _Z21sqlhaGetLocalDiskInfoPKcjPcjS1_jS1_ + 0x26C
  [4] 0x00002AAAAC523C5F _Z16sqlhaGetDiskInfoPKcS0_jPcjS1_jS1_ + 0x29F
  [5] 0x00002AAAAC521CA0 _Z16sqlhaCreateMountPKcS0_m + 0x350
  [6] 0x00002AAAACDE8D5D _Z26sqlbDMSAddContainerRequestP12SQLB_POOL_CBP16SQLB_POOLCONT_CBP12SQLB_GLOBALSP14SQLB_pfParIoCbbm + 0x90D
  [7] 0x00002AAAACE14FF9 _Z29sqlbDoDMSAddContainerRequestsP12SQLB_POOL_CBP16SQLB_POOLCONT_CBjP26SQLB_AS_CONT_AND_PATH_INFOP12SQLB_GLOBALS + 0x2D9
  [8] 0x00002AAAACE0C20F _Z17sqlbDMSCreatePoolP12SQLB_POOL_CBiP16SQLB_POOLCONT_CBbP12SQLB_GLOBALS + 0x103F
  [9] 0x00002AAAACDB1EAC _Z13sqlbSetupPoolP12SQLB_GLOBALSP12SQLB_POOL_CBPKciiiihiP19SQLB_CONTAINER_SPECllblsib + 0xE4C
```

-> it is an issue with /proc/mounts access, not the target path itself, where i can write with no issues:

```
[db2v111@rhel-hadrs ~]$ echo "test" > /db2data/testfile
```

If that would be path access issue:

```
chmod o+rx /proc
chmod a-rw /db2data
```

then an error during the "CREATE TABLESPACE" redo on standby will be different:

```
2019-06-21-03.07.29.175486+120 I35023E592            LEVEL: Error
PID     : 10379                TID : 46912992438016  PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2v111              NODE : 000            DB   : SAMPLE
APPHDL  : 0-4492               APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.190621005919
HOSTNAME: rhel-hadrs.kkuduk.com
EDUID   : 61                   EDUNAME: db2redom (SAMPLE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services, sqlbCreateAndLockParent, probe:918
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8402001E=-2080243682=SQLB_CONTAINER_NOT_ACCESSIBLE
          "Container not accessible"
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Failed at directory /db2data.

2019-06-21-03.07.29.175799+120 I35616E619            LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 10379                TID : 46912992438016  PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2v111              NODE : 000            DB   : SAMPLE
APPHDL  : 0-4492               APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.190621005919
HOSTNAME: rhel-hadrs.kkuduk.com
EDUID   : 61                   EDUNAME: db2redom (SAMPLE) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services, sqlbCreateAndLockParent, probe:722
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x8402001E=-2080243682=SQLB_CONTAINER_NOT_ACCESSIBLE
          "Container not accessible"
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Failed to create a portion of the path /db2data/testts2
```

(few more errors follow pointing directly to the permissions on /db2data)

This proves it is the /proc access issue and you need to debug it with your OS team. Perhaps /proc gets completely unmounted? 
In any case, the actual issue is db2sysc process hitting `EACCES` running `fopen` on `/proc/mounts` and you need  debug it further with OS team.

Edit:

When it comes to the debugging and proving the error is returned by the OS, we would have to trace open() syscalls done by Db2. `Strace` can do that, but overhead is too high for a production system. If you can get `SystemTap` installed on the system, I suggest a script like this (this is a basic version):

```
probe nd_syscall.open.return 
{   
    if ( user_string( @entry( pointer_arg(1) ) ) =~ ".*mounts") 
    {   
        printf("exec: %s pid: %d uid: %d (euid: %d) gid: %d (egid: %d) run open(%s) rc: %d\n", execname(), pid(), uid(), euid(), gid(), egid(), user_string(@entry(pointer_arg(1)), "-"), returnval() )
    } 
}
```

it uses `nd_syscall` probe, so it will work even without kernel debuginfo package. You can run it like this:

```
$ stap open.stap 
exec: cat pid: 24159 uid: 0 (euid: 0) gid: 0 (egid: 0) run open(/proc/mounts) rc: 3
exec: cat pid: 24210 uid: 0 (euid: 0) gid: 0 (egid: 0) run open(/proc/mounts) rc: 3
exec: cat pid: 24669 uid: 1111 (euid: 1111) gid: 1001 (egid: 1001) run open(/proc/mounts) rc: 3
exec: cat pid: 24734 uid: 1111 (euid: 1111) gid: 1001 (egid: 1001) run open(/proc/mounts) rc: -13
exec: cat pid: 24891 uid: 1111 (euid: 1111) gid: 1001 (egid: 1001) run open(/proc/self/mounts) rc: -13
exec: ls pid: 24971 uid: 1111 (euid: 1111) gid: 1001 (egid: 1001) run open(/proc/mounts) rc: -13
```

-> at some point I've revoked access from /proc and open attempt failed with -13 (`EACCES`). You just need to enable it on the system when you see the error and see if something is logged when Db2 fails.

Comment: You did mention that you have to reboot to solve the problem, right? So the question is whether you will be able to run that after seeing the error (but before the reboot). 
I've edited the main answer to to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The output of the cat /proc/mounts, cat /proc/self/mounts, mount  was ok after seeing the error and before reboot, I have changed the permission of /proc as your suggestion (chmod o+rx /proc) but the problem remains.

Comment: @Sara o+rx should be the default anyway. Could you please confirm that the error is still:


FUNCTION: DB2 Common, OSSe, ossGetDiskInfo, probe:130
MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000001=-1879048191=ECF_ACCESS_DENIED
          Access denied
CALLED  : OS, -, fopen                            OSERR: EACCES (13)
DATA #1 : String, 12 bytes
/proc/mounts


? If yes, then you need to raise that to OS vendor - that some process has intermittent problems with access to `/proc/mounts`. Typically random errors like this are caused by some antivirus software, Guardium or some kind of interception library.

Comment: Yes the error is as you mentioned, I will report it to os vendor, thanks for your guidance

Comment: @Sara
I'm aware an error like this might be tricky to investigate (and prove to OS vendor if they will not trust why db2diag.log says), but if you see it frequently you can trace the error outside of Db2. "strace" would be one option, but overhead would be too high for a production system. Using SystemTap might be the best option. I've added an example to the main answer.